# How assign some tasks to GPU

Tags: kernel, task, gpu, scheduling, multicore

I've to assign some tasks, that usually run on CPU, to GPU! is there a way to do this? For ex. If i want assign the scp process to GPU I've to rewrite process code and kernel code? 
thank you and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 3):

You can not just tell a program to run on a GPU instead of a CPU. A GPU works very differently: it is designed to execute single instructions over multiple pieces of data ([SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)) whereas we typically think of a CPU as executing a single instruction for a single peice of data ([SISD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SISD)). For example, a GPU may be used to perform the same matrix operations on every single vertex in a 3D scene, while a CPU may be used to calculate X * 11.

There are toolkits that allow a programmer to write code for GPUs, such as NVIDIA's [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/category/zone/cuda-zone), which will allow you to move some computations to the GPU. But remember that this is not going to work for just any program; the program must allow for parallelism. A good example is [hashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/), a password cracker which uses utilizes GPUs to achieve much better performance than CPU only crackers.

Comment: Ok. And if i want assign scp to GPU, i've to rewrite the process code? thanks

Comment: Yup. You will need to rewrite the program's source to using a framework like OpenCL or CUDA. This is not a trivial task... and some programs would not benefit from being moved to the GPU.

Comment: For scp in particular, first look through the source code to see if any parts of it can be done in parallel. Just a guess... but it doesn't seem like scp would be a good candidate.